# How can I write a validation that will ensure an existing association cannot be changed in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, associations

I have seen many questions asking how to validate the presence of an association, but this question is a bit more complex.

Say I have three models, a `Plane`, a `Pilot`, and a `Flight`.

A `Plane` can have one `Pilot` and one `Flight`.

Once a `Plane` has been assigned a `Pilot`, it can then be assigned a `Flight`.

**I would like to write some validation code to ensure that once a `Plane` has both a `Flight` and a `Pilot`, the `Pilot` cannot be changed.** So I would like this test to pass:

```
describe Plane do
    context "before updating" do
        it "ensures that the pilot cannot be changed if the plane has any flights" do
            plane        = Plane.create!
            plane.pilot  = Pilot.create!
            plane.flight = Flight.create!

            hijacker = Pilot.create!
            plane.pilot = hijacker

            plane.save.should be_false
            plane.errors[:base].should include "Can't change the pilot while in-flight"
        end
    end
end
```

I would love some insight as to what techniques are available to accomplish this. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with a custom validation that checks the changed record (sitting in memory) against the underlying record that's actually in the database.

```
class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_on_update :pilot_cannot_be_changed

  def pilot_cannot_be_changed
    errors.add(:pilot, "cannot be changed while in-flight.") 
      if pilot.id != Plane.find(id).pilot.id
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dobry. This is nice and simple. FYI, I received a deprecation warning when I tried to use validate_on_update. Apparently the new syntax would be :validate :pilot_cannot_be_changed, :on => :update.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own validation to ensure this..
but that wouldn't return false to you in the moment you assign a pilot, but at the end, when you save the plane.

So here is simpler version:

```
class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base

  def pilot=(val)
    return false if self.pilot && self.flight
    @pilot = val
    # I'm not sure about this line above, you can use something like this (or both lines)
    # write_attribute(:pilot_id, val.id)
  end

end
```

Hope this helps (or at least navigate you the right direction).

Regards, NoICE

Comment: Thanks, @noICE. When I looked at my test again, I realized I don't need for it to return false right away after all - on save is fine. I've edited my question to reflect this. Thanks for the answer, I hadn't thought of overriding the setter method.